# How to introduce dynamic sorting in Query annotated JPQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have defined the following method to retrieve application matching supplied criteria with Pagination support as well as sorting by dynamic column name.

```
@Repository
public interface ApplicationsRepository extends JpaRepository<Applications, Long> 
 @Query(name = "Applications.searchApplication")
Page<Application> search(@Param("roleId")Long userTypeId, @Param("appStatusId")Long appStatusId,
        @Param("searchParam") String searchParam, Pageable pageRequest, 
        @Param("queueType") String queueType);
```

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/NamedQuery.java), I found  "Finder method %s is backed " + "by a NamedQuery and must "
                    + "not contain a sort parameter as we cannot modify the query! Use @Query instead!"

I am creating  Pageable in the following way:

```
Direction direction = inputDirection == null ? Sort.Direction.DESC : Sort.Direction.ASC;
Sort sort = inputOrderBy == null ? null : new Sort(direction, inputOrderBy);
Pageable pageable =new PageRequest(inPageNo, pagination.inPageSize(), sort);
```

My concern is that the generated Oracle Query contains "fetch first ? rows only" but **no order by clause**.

Any help in this issue will be really helpful.

**Environment**:

spring-data-jpa:1.11.4.RELEASE

hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.12.Final

Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation

OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

Comment: Cant we use a query and add the order by clause on the basis of the flag you get from request

Comment: and if yet we have to do it this way can you share the entire code then maybe we can think of the solution

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee would you share with your `@Query` ? I mean `Applications.searchApplication`

Answer (score 0):

You already found the error message. Just do what it says:

Specify your query using `@Query` including the count query that needs to be executed in order to create a `Page`

Comment: Thanks.After following the error message, I have successfully archived the sorting & pagination. Its not mandatory to supply the count query, right?

Comment: In many cases, Spring Data JPA will construct the count query on its own. If it doesn't throw exceptions it does the right thing.

Comment: If this solves the problem please accept it (click the checkmark) and upvote it. Especially the checkmark makes it obvious to others finding the question what solves the problem.